# How to paste custom code when I create a method automatically in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods, auto-generate

In the IntelliJ IDEA I can create automatically a method.
I write the name of the method and if it doesn't exist, the IDE prompts to create it.

I want IDEA to paste the code `//TODO: write method ${nameOfMethod}` in the body, when it creates a new method automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: You can write your own template, but I can't imagine why this would be useful.  I know Eclipse does it, but I always thought it looked lame.  Why don't you just write the method?  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/generating-code.html

Comment: Yeah why put that sentence ! Eclipse does it and we need to remove it ! But you want to add it :/

Comment: That would actually be very useful in preventing bugs in the code caused by forgetting to write the method. It should put `// TODO: implement` (which causes a marker to appear in the IDE) followed by `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` to make sure you don't call it before you implement it.

Comment: Edit the existing template-all the code snippets are customizable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution.
The solution:

1. Open Settings.
2. Open File and Code Templates.
3. Open New Method Body.
4. Paste the code: `//TODO: to write the method ${METHOD_NAME}`

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this also works with the older IDEA 14, for anyone still stuck on that one.